# Setting connection Apache Derby in IntelliJ

Tags: java, database, intellij-idea, derby

I'm using IntelliJ as IDE.
My teacher gave me some code already.

I have a Java class AnimalSurvey (pojo) that creates a  database animalsurvey.

Below is its constructor.

```
    public AnimalSurvey() {


    System.out.println("AnimalSurvey starting in " + framework + " mode.");

    try {
        /*
         * The driver is installed by loading its class. In an embedded
         * environment, this will start up Derby, since it is not already
         * running.
         */
        Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
        System.out.println("Loaded the appropriate driver.");

        props = new Properties();
        props.put("user", "app");
        props.put("password", "app");

        /*
         * The connection specifies create=true to cause the database to be
         * created. To remove the database, remove the directory
         * animalsurvey and its contents. The directory animalsurvey will be
         * created under the directory that the system property
         * derby.system.home points to, or the current directory if
         * derby.system.home is not set.
         */


        String dataPath =System.getProperty("user.home");
        dataPath += "/DerbyDB/";

        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(protocol
            //  + "c:\\cloudscape_db\\animalsurvey;create=true", props); //windows
        + dataPath+"animalsurvey;create=false", props);                  //Macos


        System.out
                .println("Connected to and created database animalsurvey");

        conn.setAutoCommit(false);

    } catch (Throwable e) {
        System.out.println("exception thrown:");

        if (e instanceof SQLException) {
            printSQLError((SQLException) e);
        } else {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

And an initialize() method in this class AnimalSurvey:

```
public void initialize()throws SQLException{

    /*
     * Creating a statement lets us issue commands against the
     * connection.
     */
    s = conn.createStatement();

    s.execute("drop table surveyresults");


    /*
     * We create a table, add a few rows, and update one.
     */
    s.execute("create table surveyresults (id int NOT NULL , surveyoption varchar (20) NOT NULL , votes int NOT NULL , constraint surveyresults_id primary key (id)) ");
    s.execute("insert into surveyresults (id,surveyoption,votes) values (1, 'Dog', 0)");
    s.execute("insert into surveyresults (id,surveyoption,votes) values (2, 'Cat', 0)");
    s.execute("insert into surveyresults (id,surveyoption,votes) values (3, 'Bird', 0)");
    s.execute("insert into surveyresults (id,surveyoption,votes) values (4, 'Snake', 0)");
    s.execute("insert into surveyresults (id,surveyoption,votes) values (5, 'None', 0)");
    /*
     * We select the rows and verify the results.
     */
    rs = s.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM surveyresults ORDER BY surveyoption");
    rmd = rs.getMetaData();
}
```

Now I have Java servlet that contains the following code, a AnimalSurvey object is initialized and then the initialize() method on this object is defined:

```
    AnimalSurvey dataObject = new AnimalSurvey();
    dataObject.initialize();
```

When I run my web program and end up in that java servlet, I always get a HTTP Status 500 ? Internal Server Error and it gives me the next exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
data.AnimalSurvey.initialize(AnimalSurvey.java:184)
be.SurveyServlet.doPost(SurveyServlet.java:25)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
```

So it looks like in the AnimalSurvey class, in the initialize method, the following code (private Connection conn was set on null in that class), is still null when I execute the code.

```
s = conn.createStatement();
```

It's a lot of code, I know and I hope it makes sense.
My teacher also gave me the next info in order to have access to the database:
'jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/surveyresults;user=app;password=app;

But how do I get Apache Derby working? Do I need to download the drivers? And where in IntelliJ do I set a connection to this database?

Comment: From the connection string provided it looks like you will need to have an instance of the Apache Derby database running on your local machine, when running it will be listening on localhost port 1527 by default (as per the connection string).
Have a look at https://db.apache.org/derby/quick_start.html

Comment: Also see: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.15/getstart/